# Synchronization on App Engine

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, synchronization

I'm building an application using Google App Engine.  The application consists of several servlets, one of which has a static member object that holds a lot of internal state.  Multiple Android phones contact this servlet, causing the servlet to update the state of the static member object.  However, when multiple phones happen to talk to the server at the same time, I get synchronization issues in which the static object is being modified by multiple threads at once.  I've tried throwing in some synchronized blocks, but this does not seem to help.

I think the reason has something to do with how App Engine spawns threads for HTTP requests, but I'm not sure.  What's the standard way to synchronize access to shared objects in App Engine?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GAE app can be started on different servers, there can be, and will be few instances at one time. Any instance can be started or killed at any time, without any notice before. So, any in-memory state is useless.

You have to use or memcache service, or database instead.

Comment: So using the datastore and the associated memcache is the only way to store any state on the server?

Comment: exactly. you can use memory as 'phantom-cache', but there is also few megabytes memory limitation